# How to join 2 youtube videos with different ratios (16:9 and 4:3)?

Tags: video-editor

I need some help with the youtube video editor? I need to join 2 youtube videos but one is in 16:9 and the other in 4:3. The final result should be in 16:9. Is it possible with the youtube video editor?
Thanks

Comment: The default Youtube player is 16:9, and the Youtube video editor creates a new video, so there's no harm in just trying and making a new merged video. If it's not fine just delete it.

Comment: I tried it and in the part correspondent to the 1st video the result is still in 4:3

Comment: @vascobunes; what editing software are you using, or are you just uploading raw clips to youtube?

Comment: I have the raw videos on youtube already. I wanted only simple editing capabilities available on the youtube video editor.

Answer (score 2):

You're either going to have to resample your 4:3 video as 16:9 which will add black bars at the top and bottom, or crop the 16:9 video to fit in 4:3. Either way, the video will need to be re-edited, maybe even re-uploaded. I assume you have editor/owner access to both files?

As far as I can tell there is not way to do this on YouTube via the enhancement section on the Video Manager section. It looks like you will have to re-upload.